# Cant access kubernetes pod (minikube)

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, kubernetes

[image: This is how the service & pod looks like in kubernetes]

On the image, you can see the service and the pod.

If I execute "curl localhost" inside the container, I get a response, but I am not able to access it from outside.

What is wrong?

This is the file I run "kubectl -f on:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "wordpress-site",
        "labels": {
            "app": "web"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "wordpress",
                "image": "wp:latest",
                "imagePullPolicy": "Never",
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "containerPort": 80
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would need some more information but with what you gave me I will make the assumption you want to access it from outside the node the pod is. For this problem we can use [kubernetes services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/).

You could easy add the service configuration to the yaml file, here is the api reference for doing that: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#-strong-service-apis-strong-

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by setting:

hostNetwork: true